# Add a view when FAB is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout

My app has a Linear layout.

I want a text view to be added to this layout whenever I click the Floating Action Button( FAB ).

Also, how do I edit different parameters of the view such as text, color, size, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing that, Just add a TextView inside LinearLayout and set it's Visibility to GONE.

and inside onClickListener,

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

---

#### To save activity state...

1> We need TextView and a boolean to store its value...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

     TextView textView;    
     Boolean isTextViewVisible = true;   

     
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          {...}
          textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
          {...}
     }
}
```

2>  To hide/show textView

```
{ 
    // inside any method....
    textView.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
    isTextViewVisible = false;     // because it is not visible!!!
}
```

3> Store activity state

We need `onSaveInstanceState` method, So Press Ctrl + o and search for it, and add it.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putBoolean("isVisible", isTextViewVisible);  // storing value...
}
```

4> Restore activity state

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    {...}

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {     // if savedInstanceState is not null...
        isTextViewVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isVisible");  
       
        // It will set value for isTextViewVisible boolean from previous state

        if (isTextViewVisible == false){

            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    {...}
}
```

For more details https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks, one thing though, when I restart the app everything is again set to invisible. How do I make these changes permanent so that they remain as it is and do not disappear when I run the app again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to dynamically add multiple textviews:

```
    //you can dynamically change text size and color of this view.
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    //change margins according to your need.
    int marginLeft = 0 ,marginRight = 0 ,marginTop = 0 ,marginBottom = 0;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(marginLeft,marginTop,marginRight,marginBottom);
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    yourLinearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Hope this helps.